# MVC @Html.DropDownList Getting Error with SelectList in ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

I have a list which I created in the controller:

```
     var PayList = new[] {
      new ListEntry { Id = 1, Name = "" },
      new ListEntry { Id = 2, Name = "Yes" },  
      new ListEntry { Id = 3, Name = "No" }  

      };

     ViewBag.PayList = new SelectList(PayList, "Id", "Name");
```

In the view I have the following:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("Pay", new SelectList(ViewBag.PayList,"Id","Name"))
```

When I try to display it, it says the following:
DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'. Not sure why this is not working.

Also how do I default a value to the select list. I like to default it to "Yes". I thought there was a way to do do this from the controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use

```
@Html.DropDownList("Pay", ViewBag.PayList)
```

In your view

Answer (score 8):

Your `ViewBag.PayList` is already the type of `SelectList`.  I don't see a reason to create the `SelectList` twice, so shouldn't it just be:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Pay", ViewBag.PayList)
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownList("Pay", ViewBag.PayList as SelectList)
```

(I don't ever use the ViewBag, so I'm not sure if your version is strongly typed).

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("Pay", ViewBag.PayList as SelectList) worked for me in MVC4

Comment: I can also confirm that option with ("Pay", ViewBag.PayList as SelectList) is working for me in MVC 4, the other one ("Pay", ViewBag.PayList) is not working for me and I get an error

Comment: This is the one to use in MVC 4 +, otherwise you get the error "Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched".

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this Way:
<div id="divmsg" style="color: green; font-weight: bold">
    @ViewBag.Msg
</div>
<div id="divmsg2" style="color: red; font-weight: bold">@ViewBag.Msg2</div>
<div id="quality" style="width: 80%;" align="center">
    <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.ProjectId" id="ProjectId_" class="projectId"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.ProjectName" id="ProjectName_" class="projectName"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.UserId" class="UserId_" id="UserId"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.TempId" class="TempId_" id="TempId" />
    <div class="toggle-contents">
        <table width="100%" id="qualitygoal">
            <tr>
                <td class="even" align="left">
                    @Html.Label("Project Id")
                </td>
                <td class="even" align="left">
                    @ViewBag.ProjectId
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td class="projectname" align="left">
                    @Html.Label("Project Name")
                </td>
                <td class="projectname" align="left">
                    @ViewBag.ProjectName
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>

        <table width="100%" id="qualitygoal1" class="tbl">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th align="center">DestinationColumns</th>
                    <th align="center">SourceColumns</th>


                </tr>

                @foreach (var data in Model)
                {

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span class="spanStatus" id="lblStatus_@data.TempId"  destinationID = "@data.Destination">@data.Destinationvalue</span>
                            <select class="status" id="ddlStatus_@data.TempId">
                                <option value="0">--Select--</option>
                                <option value="4">TICKET ID</option>
                                <option value="5">DESCRIPTION</option>
                                <option value="6">TICKET CATEGERY</option>
                                <option value="7">SEVIORITY/PRIORITY</option>
                                <option value="8">STATUS</option>
                                <option value="9">CREATED DATE</option>
                                <option value="10">CREATED BY</option>
                                <option value="11">ASSIGNED TO</option>
                                <option value="12">ASSIGNED DATE</option>
                                <option value="13">REPSONSE ETA</option>
                                <option value="14">RESOLUTION ETA</option>
                                <option value="15">RESPONSE DATE</option>
                                <option value="16">RESOLUTION DATE</option>
                                <option value="17">ROOT CAUSE/MODULE</option>
                                <option value="18">REOPEN FLAG (Y/N)</option>
                                <option value="19">CLOSE DATE</option>
                                <option value="20">SLA MET (Y/N)</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="spanSource" id="lblSource_@data.TempId" >@data.Source</span>
                            <input  class="Source" id="txtSource_@data.TempId" type="text" value="@data.Source" maxlength="30"  />
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <table style="width: 50%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input class="edit" id="Edit_@data.TempId" type="button" value="Edit"   />
                                        <input class="update" id="Update_@data.TempId" type="button" value="Update"  />
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="Gcancle" id="Canc_@data.TempId">
                                        <input class="gridcancel" id="Cancel_@data.TempId" type="button" value="Cancel"  />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <table style="width: 50%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input class="delete" id="Delete_@data.TempId" type="button" value="Delete"  />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div align="right">
        <input type="button" value="Add New Row" class="Add" />

        <input type="button" value="Save" class="saved" />
        <input type="button" value="Close" class="cancel" />



    </div>

</div>
```