# How to use a @Html.DropDownList with ViewBag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filtering, html-select, viewbag

I'm working with MVC4.

I've added the paging, sorting and filtering functions in an Index page.As a result, I have to add a **viewbag** parameter to the filtering **DropdownList** to keep the filtering string.

Here comes an example of a textbox with a viewbag parameter:

```
@Html.TextBox("name",ViewBag.CurrentFilterName as string)
```

This works well.

I want to add a **viewbag** parameter to the **DropDownList**.
Here comes my HTML code for this DropDownList:

```
@Html.DropDownList("type","All",ViewBag.CurrentFilterType as string).
```

This is wrong.

Could someone tell me how to correct it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I managed to hit a solution? Can I have some help?

Answer (score 0):

conceivable that they can be: `@Html.DropDownList("type", ViewBag.CurrentFilterType)`.

Check this: [MVC @Html.DropDownList Getting Error with SelectList in ViewBag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086784/mvc-html-dropdownlist-getting-error-with-selectlist-in-viewbag)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:
View:

```
<td id="dropdown">
    @Html.DropDownList("Parameter", ViewBag.Parameter as SelectList)
</td>
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Parameter = new SelectList(_dataModel.GetWeightage(), "Parameter");
    return View();
}
```